# Plotting Ocean Currents MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot vector currents over a `pcolor` of current velocity. But it's not working.

I tried this code:

```
% Plot speed with explicit zorder
figure
pcolor(X1', Y1', speed)
% shading interp  % Interpolate colors
colorbar

hold on
% Plot vectors
m_quiver(X1', Y1', u, v)
```

`m_quiver` is not plotting over the `pcolor`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please [edit[ your post to contain a [mre]? I.e. add some sample data (a simple `rand()` dataset would probably do), as well as a screenshot of your current output. Also `m_quiver()` doesn't seem to be a built-in function. Thus, please add the source code (or link to, if it's not yours) as well.

Comment: `m_quiver.m` is a function in the external [M_Map](https://www.eoas.ubc.ca/~rich/map.html) toolbox. They also have an `m_pcolor` function (and a whole lot of well known matlab function name prefixed with `m_`). If you are not using `m_pcolor` for your initial plot, could you not simply use the MATLAB built-in `quiver.m` for the second part of your plot ?

Comment: i tried m_pcolor and it worked,  thank you!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.